# How to translate GPS coordinates to a place?

Tags: android, google-places-api, geocoding, google-places

I'm building an app that uses Google places API to get current place if the internet is on. If the internet is off, I use the GPS to fetch and store the coordinates; when, later, the internet is available, I want to translate these coordinates to a place (pass to places API).

Can anybody, please, help?

I couldn't find any method in places API that takes coordinates. I tried to convert coordinates to place id and later use it in places API, but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you do in Places API takes coordinates in the location field.
For instance:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

So if you already have the coordinates you should just make a request to the API, here you have all the info you need:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests